# When I access my new site it shows up as 'Index of /'

Tags: file, indexing, structure, uploading

When I access my new site it shows up as:

`Index of  /`

[wallstreetprotestors.com](http://wallstreetprotestors.com)

I'm new to this and haven't finished site, but I don't understand the index /? I noticed the index file changes when I upload the index page to the server -- it is not the same size?

Comment: What files are on the server, and what you upload?

Answer (score 0):

The index page should be named `index (.html or .php eg.)` if you cannot/don't want to change your server's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an index file. You should rename that file that exists to `index.html` and it should work fine for you. Your Apache configuration is set to show the directory structure when no index file is found, rather than showing a 403 Not Authorized.

Answer (score 0):

With the majority of hosts, your main page (the index page) must be named 'index.html' rather than an arbitrary name of your choosing - this is then used as the index when opening a page at its root (i.e., when you don't specify a specific page in the url).